# polr function in Ordinal Regression

Tags: r, regression

I am working on a dataset where CLASS is my target variable with d levels (HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW). Now I am trying to apply Ordinal Regression. I split my data into training and testing. Then I run this command.

```
polr(Class~., data= training, Hess = TRUE) -> reg
```

It keeps on running that is it never gets executed. I've left it for over an hour and this command was still running. I could not run any other commands until this command is done, and ultimately I have to terminate my R.

Why is this command not stopping? Am I missing something? Is there any condition that has to be fulfilled to apply Ordinal?

```
ind <- sample(2, nrow(realdata), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7,0.3))
training <- realdata[ind==1,]
testing <- realdata[ind==2,]

library(MASS)

model <- polr(Class~., data= training, Hess = TRUE)
```

This command should run so I can get a summary and continue with other commands but I am stuck here.

Here is the structure of my data that I'm working on:

```
str(realdata)

'data.frame':   4999 obs. of  19 variables:

 $ Customer        : Factor w/ 4137 levels " Abeera Bajwa",..: 782 3756 3756 3521 2531 2749 782 2260 3386 4048 ...

 $ Customer.No     : Factor w/ 4294 levels "001-000161-01",..: 1074 1118 1118 1080 1102 1119 1074 1087 1099 1135 ...

 $ Shop            : Factor w/ 71 levels "Abbotabad","Atriium Perfume Kiosk",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

 $ Invoice         : int  29810 29824 29829 29846 29800 29802 29808 29809 29826 29837 ...

 $ Quantity        : int  1 2 1 1 7 2 7 2 4 2 ...

 $ Sales           : Factor w/ 707 levels "-100","1,000",..: 707 306 394 306 491 306 500 479 403 320 ...

 $ Cash.Amt        : int  910 2200 2950 2205 4740 2205 4925 4610 3210 2580 ...

 $ Credit.Card.Amt : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

 $ Net.Sales       : Factor w/ 1215 levels "1,000","1,003",..: 1212 396 476 397 712 397 734 702 540 436 ...

 $ Mens.Wear       : Factor w/ 17 levels "0","0\\","1",..: 3 3 1 1 3 1 9 1 1 1 ...

 $ Womens.Wear     : int  0 1 1 0 2 1 1 1 1 2 ...

 $ Kids.Wear       : int  0 0 0 1 2 1 3 1 1 0 ...

 $ Foot.Wear       : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 ...

 $ Fragrant        : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 ...

 $ Class           : Factor w/ 3 levels "H","L","M": 2 3 3 3 1 3 1 1 3 3 ...

 $ Date            : Factor w/ 36 levels "1/4/2016","1/4/2017",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

 $ Year            : int  2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 ...

 $ Month           : Factor w/ 12 levels "April","August",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...

 $ Customer.Address: Factor w/ 1 level "##_#/#,#####################################": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: You should probably pre-process your data before running any regression. There are variables in there that should *not* be factors passed into a regression model (e.g. `Sales` / `Net.Sales` should definitely be numeric, and `Date` should be, well, date), while others should not be passed in at all (e.g. `Customer` / `Customer.No`).

Comment: I converted Sales and Net.Sales into numeric and then run this code. I am getting this error. Can you please tell me how to resolve this error?                          
  model <- polr(Class~ Invoice + Quantity + Sales + Net.Sales + Cash.Amt + Credit.Card.Amt + Womens.Wear + Kids.Wear + Foot.Wear + Fragrant, data= training, Hess = TRUE)          Error in polr(Class ~ Invoice + Quantity + Sales + Net.Sales + Cash.Amt +  : 
attempt to find suitable starting values failed  Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

Comment: Can't advise on the specifics w/o seeing your data, but you may want to start out with a simpler formula (e.g. `Class ~ Sales`), & add on more variables rogressively only if you are sure the new variables would be useful. Also, shouldn't Class be an ordered factor?

Comment: Is this the correct command to convert Class into ordered factor? realdata$Class <-as.ordered(realdata$Class) .But even after this my polr command does not run. Can I apply logistic regression on this Class variable?